# How to create a view for a Structured Buffer under DirectX 12?

Tags: graphics, 3d, directx, directx-12

I am trying to implement instancing inside my DirectX 12 renderer.
To do so I want to use a structured buffer that store each instance transformation.
Here how it is declared in my vertex shader:

```
struct MeshTransform
{
    float4x4 mat;
};

StructuredBuffer<MeshTransform> meshTransforms : register(t0);
```

Now I need to upload that structured buffer from the CPU.
To do so I simply create a default heap initialized with the mesh transforms.
Here the problem, when I try to create the heap SRV I get this error:
**D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateShaderResourceView: The Format (0, UNKNOWN) cannot be used when creating a View of a Buffer**

Here how I create the SRV:

```
struct DirectX12StructuredBufferHandle
{
    DescriptorHandle srvDescriptorHandle;
    DescriptorHandle uavDescriptorHandle;
    ID3D12Resource* buffer = nullptr;
};

void DirectX12Renderer::createSRV(DirectX12StructuredBufferHandle& dst)
{
    D3D12_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc = {};
    srvDesc.Shader4ComponentMapping = D3D12_DEFAULT_SHADER_4_COMPONENT_MAPPING;
    srvDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
    srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;

    dst.srvDescriptorHandle = m_cbs_srv_uavAllocator->allocate({ dst.buffer }, srvDesc);
}
```

So DirectX doesn't like the specified **DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN**. What should I put then?
I checked the Microsoft Mini Engine code they seems to use DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN when creating buffers:
https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/MiniEngine/Core/GpuBuffer.cpp?plain=1#L189-216

What am I missing?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: you didn't fill out the `D3D12_BUFFER_SRV Buffer` member. In particular, it needs to know the `StructureByteStride` https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/b5f92e2251ee83db4d4c795b3cba5d470c52eaf8/MiniEngine/Core/GpuBuffer.cpp?plain=1#L195-L197

Comment: And it worked thank you.  I thought it was complaining about srvDesc.Format.
Please can you post answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't fill out the `D3D12_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC::Buffer` member.

With `DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN` the runtime doesn't know the element stride so you have to specify in `D3D12_BUFFER_SRV::StructureByteStride`

https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/b5f92e2251ee83db4d4c795b3cba5d470c52eaf8/MiniEngine/Core/GpuBuffer.cpp?plain=1#L195-L197